# How to specify the size of a MessageDlg box?

Tags: messagebox, lazarus

On Lazarus I have this code:

```
MessageDlg('HRS: Data error!.',
       'Either the system is not properly configured or you have an error' + chr(13) +
       'that requires expert assistance. This may be due to several reasons like' + chr(13) +
       'bad hardware, tampering, etc. Please contact Marha Online or your admin.' + chr(13) +
       'Please do not continue to use the HRS software until it is fixed.', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
```

The output is like this:

[image]

I am using chr(13) to break line but as you can see the lines are broken elsewhere as well. I'm also concerned about how this will show on Windows... BTW, I'm using Ubuntu.

Is there a way to control the size of this box or a way around it?
Thanks!

Comment: Just a hint. Better use [`LineEnding`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/lineending.html) constant instead of hardcoded `chr(13)`. It's target OS dependent, so you won't need to change it e.g. to `#13#10` if your target platform will be Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no, there's no way you can control the size of a `MessageDlg`. By design, `MessageDlg` and friends are meant to behave in pretty much a standarrd way.

Although I'm guessing you already thought about it, a way around it would be to simply create your own. That way you would have much more control over it than just its size.

And a side note: I would place `LineEndings` *only on paragraph endings*. These dialogs try to adjust to their content, so I guess it's the only way they'd play nice... JMHO.